# How do I get Thunderbird localized?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Natty and installed Thunderbird as well as the locale-de package, but it is still in English. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you may be a victim of this issue: [Thunderbird: localization not installed automatically](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/534417).
The workaround is run "System - Administration - Language Support" to install the missing Thunderbird language packs.

Please confirm if it works.

Comment: The user was last seen on May 10 at 15:13, I doubt it will confirm :)